# Auto update column with new high number

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet which is collecting data from a site which users are bidding on certain prizes.

[User Bid Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYfOV.png)

In the screen shot above, lot 1 has 3 bids.  I’d like to know how to add the highest bid (£60) in the Current Highest bid column and update when a new high bid comes in?

Many thanks

I know about Maximum: The maximum value is the largest value in the dataset, or the value that all other values in the dataset are less than or equal to - But I need to auto update based on a new high bid on a certain lot, can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(unique(filter(regexextract(E2:E,"^.*? - "),E2:E<>"")),lambda(Σ, Σ&maxifs(F:F,index(--regexmatch(E:E,Σ)),1)))
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting this error when trying to replicate: "You've entered too few arguments for this function"?

Comment: Share a test copy of your sample sheet showcasing this error so that we can troubleshoot it directly

Comment: apologies, I was entering it wrong it has worked.  Thank you!!