# Updating WordPress page with google sheet data on update

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets

I have a google sheet which is collecting data from a site which users are bidding on certain prizes. I have a column updating with the current highest bid for a certain prize (lot) - this can be seen here: [Auto update column with new high number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77307723/auto-update-column-with-new-high-number).

I am now needing to export the current highest bid and update a page in WordPress i.e. lot 2 is 15 so I'd need that figure to update here:

[[image: Current Highest Bid(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWsCj.png)]

Many thanks!

I am really needing pointing in the right direction as im at a loss with where to start.

Comment: Start by defining how exactly you want this to work bit more specific. Do you want any update in the Google Sheet to trigger the update on your WP site automatically? Then you will probably have to go look into what mechanism GS provides to "notify" external systems of such updates. Or do you perhaps only want to download your data from GS as a CSV or something, and then import that data into your WP, triggered manually? Then I would look into plugins such as WP All Import.

Comment: And what exactly you need to update in your WP, we can't tell from that screenshot either. We don't know if this is a specific post type (something like a "product", or maybe even an _actual_ WooCommerce product), whether that info is stored separately into a specific field or just part of the post content, ...

Comment: Id prefer it to trigger when the google sheet updates.  What it is: its a WP page with static content - literally just images with text underneath, 34 in total.

Comment: Then you'll probably want to implement some sort of Webhook functionality - https://medium.com/@eyalgershon/sending-a-webhook-for-new-or-updated-rows-in-google-sheets-e0c9d6a8cb45, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690332/trigger-webhook-when-google-sheet-edited

Comment: _"What it is: its a WP page with static content - literally just images with text underneath, 34 in total."_ - then you'll have to figure out how to "access" the correct parts of that content, in order to update it only in the relevant places. Giving elements specific classes, and then use either a DOM parser or regular expressions to modify their content, could be one way to go. Another would be that you separate the data storage from the actual page, and then implement some shortcode to fetch & display the data in the relevant places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this simply and quickly, try writing a [plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) to implement a [custom shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/). The custom shortcode implementation could do one of two things.

1. Use php code to use the google sheets api to retrieve the current bid data and display it on the WordPress page.
2. Use php code to write out some Javascript to the page that uses the google sheets api, from your users' browsers, to get the data and display it.

These choices have the downside that they poll your sheet. That is, they do a lookup n the sheet every time a user refreshes a page on your site. You could hit a rate limit on the sheet api. You can mitigate this problem by using [transients](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_transient/) to cache the results of your lookups for a half-minute or so. The WordPress page data will then lag the real time data by a few seconds. If that's tolerable, it's a good way to avoid a rate limit.

Your shortcode might look like this:

```
[oxenauction lot=2]
```

You'll put this into your WordPress pages something like this:

```
£<div class="price">[oxenauction lot=2]<\div>
```

The shortcode implementation (the first choice above) will fetch the sheet data and emit it as HTML, something like this.

```html
£<div class="price">75<\div>
```

Once you have a working shortcode, create a page or post on your site for every lot in your auction. Put the shortcode mentioning the lot number where you want the current bid to appear. Use WordPress content editing to insert the text and imagery describing the lot.

You could also set up a webhook, where the sheet sends an outbound api request to your WordPress site with every change. That's a bigger deal to implement in WordPress because you'll need to implement a [custom REST api endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/). Tooling up to create and test that kind of code takes some time.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer! I believe I can do this, I have 3 weeks to implement and will start hopefully on Monday.  I'll let you know and be sure to give you credit here! Thank you again!!!